# How to use Mokito to Mock methods of local scope objects passing to other method as a parameter

Tags: java, mockito

Suppose, I have a class like below :

```
class A {
    public B method1 (){
    B b = new B()
    method2(b);
    return b;
    }
    private void method2(B b) {
        try {
        b.method3();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception(e); // code to be covered in UT
        }
    }
}
```

I want to test it with mockito. So that I can throw an Exception from call `b.method3();` and I can cover the Catch block code.
Please help on same.

I tried the below code but it is not working:

```
    @Test
    public void test1() {
        B b = null;
        try {
        B bObjMock = Mockito.mock(B.class);
        Mockito.when(bObjMock.method3()
                .thenThrow(new Exception());
        PowerMockito.whenNew(B.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(bObjMock);

        A a = new A();
        b = a.method1();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Assert.assertTrue(true);
        }
        Assert.assertNull(b);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO :). Please apply standard java formatting to your code, to make easier for others to read your code.

Comment: Could you please explain what is not working? From your code I see one problem which actually just might be a typo and you have it correctly in your real code. But in "Mockito.when(bObjMock.method3().thenThrow(new Exception());" the one brace is incorrect. It should actually read "Mockito.when(bObjMock.method3()).thenThrow(new Exception());" -> There is a closing bracket here directly after method3(). If you tell what exactly is going wrong I could take a look.